# object has no attribute 'mogrify'

Tags: postgresql, python-2.7, psycopg2

I am trying to insert data into a postgres DB using python package psycopg2.

```
def insertIntoDB(__insertSQL__,patternString,data,conn):
    conn = connectToDB()
    cur = conn.cursor  
    #print patternString
    insert_arg = ','.join(cur.mogrify("("+patternString+")",x) for x in data)
    cur.execute(__insertSQL__+insert_arg)
    conn.commit()
```

When I execute the script I get the following error:

> AttributeError: 'builtin_function_or_method' object has no attribute 'mogrify'

I have already installed the 64 bit installer for psycopg2 in my windows machine.

Any thoughts on this is much appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In this line:

```
cur = conn.cursor
```

you should be doing:

```
cur = conn.cursor()
```

What happens when you do the former is that you're not using a cursor you're using the built-in function or method which creates the cursor.

Comment: `def conn(host, db, username, password):
    # connect to the PostgreSQL server
    print('Connecting to the database...')
    psycopg2.connect("host={} dbname={} user={} password={}".format(host, db, username, password))
    cur = conn.cursor()`

I get an error

`cur = conn.cursor()
AttributeError: 'function' object has no attribute 'cursor'`